# Clone a 500GB internal hard disk to 256gb internal SSD

Tags: clone

I just added a new 256GB SSD in the place of my 500GB HDD and I used a caddy to add the hdd to the laptop in place of a CD Drive. My files including the OS i.e. Ubuntu is currently on my old HDD, how do I transfer it all to the new SSD?

Comment: Reduce the partition of your 500gb to the size of your SSD. The original partition may not be larger than the capacity of your clone target

Comment: How do I do that without deleting files? Currently the HDD has only 150GB of used space. But it has 3 partition of 537 MB with 1.2% used space, 500GB with 35.2% used space and 1.1MB.

Comment: I'm a newbie, and I tried partitioning before but I ended up deleting everything on the sd-card.

Comment: In that case, it might be a better course of action to get someone more experienced to do it for you.

Comment: Please edit your question to show information about partitions on the HDD - size, type, %used. You have given some of this in comments. Also, what is the "sd-card", a 3rd drive?

Comment: It is risky to edit the partition table in order to make it work to clone from the bigger HDD to the smaller SSD. I think it is a better idea to create a fresh operating system on the SSD and then, later on, copy the files you want to keep from the HDD to the SSD. Do the copying at the file level instead of cloning. It might also be a good idea to create a dedicated backup in a separate drive, where you keep backup copies of all the files that are important.